# Unconfirmed Transactions From a Year ago

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I have two unconfirmed transactions, one from one year ago and another from about 16 months ago.  I am not sure if they are gone for good or if I can try something like a 2x transaction etc.  I'm running bitcoin core, latest rev on a mac.  I don't have enough in my wallet to even cover a double transaction.  Any viable advice would be appreciated.

edit:  it appears when I tried to send two separate transactions at the time, I never sent enough for the transaction fees.

Comment: I can't believe that. 16 months unconfirmed is just crazy. I sent 0.2 BTC with a fee of ~0.14$ around 5 months ago and it went through within 4 days... Do you have the transaction IDs?

Comment: Here is one:  9679b7dc5b49e5584e1a2a38b21e11ee263311959b80eb67dfb8277a7eec71f4

Comment: There is no search result for this ID: https://blockchain.info/de/search?search=+9679b7dc5b49e5584e1a2a38b21e11ee263311959b80eb67dfb8277a7eec%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B71f4&searchbar=search

Comment: What client are you using? You may need to keep it running to make it rebroadcast on the network.

Comment: hey guys using bit core on mac...

Comment: also cannot duplicate as I don't have enough in my wallet?

Comment: Just checked the tx number, and saw there is a problem with the length. It should be 32 Bytes hex (aka 64 chars). up to "9679b7...7a7eec" I have 63 chars, then is some formatting problem, but it would be too long with "71f4" at the end. Maybe get this corrected?

Comment: hmm, but that is a direct copy out of my wallet...what can I do?

Comment: I couldn't find the transaction on any explorer. You can do a ["-zapwallettxes"](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it) to remove the two stucked transactions. Seems like a fomatting issue on stackoverflow's comments, 2 zero-width space are added before 71f4.
Seem fine when I divide them with a a space:
9679b7dc5b49e5584e1a2a38b21e11 ee263311959b80eb67dfb8277a7eec71f4

Answer (score 0):

Just create one more transaction from your previous address with current fees per byte actual value, and be happy.